# Permanent Internet Access for Host-only Adapter w. UFW Killswitch

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

According to documentation found here.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

I can establish temporary internet access for my vbox using a single host-only adapter, a static ip inside the vbox, and my UFW settings, using the following commands:

```
$sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -i vboxnet5 -s 192.168.61.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE
```

However, these commands are transient and vanish after reboot.  I can take a shortcut and set a bash script to run at boot, but I'd rather learn the proper way to do this.

Any tips?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solutuion here was quite simple.

`sudo nano /etc/ufw/before.rules`

In this section of the file:

```
#NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
```

Add:

`-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.61.0/24 -j MASQUERADE`

Now all traffic 192.168.61.0 will be sent through the host primary network interface even if it changes (i.e. wifi vs lan)